# Can you require a file directly from the /after/plugin folder?

Tags: lua, config, neovim

I decided to spring-clean and update my nvim config files/plugins, and thought I’d make proper use of the after/plug folder.
While setting up LSP (with mason, mason-lspconfig, and lspconfig), I wanted to move all the lsp language server settings out from after/plugin/lsp/init.lua to their own files (now in after/plugin/lsp/settings).

The problem is I don’t seem to be able to require them into the init.lua file.

Things I’ve tried to no avail:

```
require(‘after/plugin/lsp/settings/sumneko_lua.lua’)
require(vim.fn.stdpath("config") .. "/after/plugin/lsp/settings/sumneko_lua”)
require(vim.fn.expand('%:h').. ‘/settings/sumneko_lua’)
```

The attempt using `expand` works when I resource the file in nvim; but causes an error when starting nvim.

I understand that all the files in after/plugin are automagically sourced at startup. So if I had a file shared.lua:

```
local M = {}                                                                              
                                                                                         
function M.greet()                                                                        
  vim.notify("Hello!”)
end

return M
```

in the same folder as after/plugin/lsp/init.lua, how can I get access to the greet() function from init.lua?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite a simple solution in the end: I simply updated the paths to be searched in init.lua

```
-- nvim/init.lua
-- Allow require to look in after/plugin folder

local home_dir = os.getenv("HOME")
package.path = home_dir .. "/.config/nvim/after/plugin/?.lua;" .. package.path
```

And then I can require any file inside the after/plugin folder

e.g - `require("lsp/settings/sumneko")` or `require("lsp/shared").greet()`